# monitor changes on NSManagedObject similar to NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am implemented a class that is similar to `NSFetchedResultsController` - I call it `DKDataArray`. Unlike `NSFetchedResultsController` it doesn't fetch the objects from the database but gets them from a relation of another object.

I now want to extend it in a way that it monitors changes in its fetched objects and propagates changes to a delegate - just like `NSFetchedResultsController` does.

This is the delegate method I'd like to support:

```
@protocol DKDataArrayDelegate

@optional
- (void)dataArray:(DKDataArray *)dataArray
  didChangeObject:(id)anObject
          atIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end
```

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` of
the managed object context. From the documentation:

> Posted when values of properties of objects contained in a managed
>   object context are changed. The notification is posted during
>   `processPendingChanges`, after the changes have been processed, 
>   ...
>   The notification object is the managed object context. The userInfo
>   dictionary contains the following keys: `NSInsertedObjectsKey`,
>   `NSUpdatedObjectsKey`, and `NSDeletedObjectsKey`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that...I assume I'd have to test all changed objects against the objects in my array? Depending on the amount of changes, this could probably be a lot.

Comment: @de.: I don't know a better solution :-) (You could use Key-Value-Observing to track changes to all objects in your array, but then you will not get notified about *new* objects.)

Comment: I had the vague idea that I should maybe observe my objects directly, what do you think?

Comment: @de.: That's what I meant with my last comment. You won't get notified about new objects, and you somehow would have to remove the observer for deleted objects. - So I *assume* that the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification is the better solution.

Comment: Ok now this makes me think I should maybe monitor the parent object where I get my related objects array from – that's probably the only chance to get notified about new objects.

Comment: Ok, I'm on it. Will probably take some time to test all edge cases. Thanks!

Comment: @de.: Good luck! - I strongly assume that `NSFetchedResultsController` also uses the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` for change tracking: If you set a breakpoint in the `controllerWillChangeContent` FRC delegate method you can see a `_postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:` method in the stack backtrace.